# Macros inside pstricks parameters

Tags: macros, pstricks

I would like to create a command to pass easily from color to black-and-white pictures. For this purpose, I would like to use a `\newif \ifBlackAndWhite` together with a macro `\myCommand` such that if `\ifBlackAndWhitetrue`, then

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}
```

becomes

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=none, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}
```

and if `\ifBlackAndWhitefalse`, then it becomes

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}
```

Is it possible to define such a macro? A naive template below...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand{\myCommand}{...}

\newif\ifBlackAndWhite  \BlackAndWhitefalse    

\ifBlackAndWhite
\renewcommand{\myCommand}{...}
\fi
  
\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=none, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the expansion order. For simple commands like `\pscircle` you can define variants that do that for you (`\ePScircle` below). For more complicated commands this is not so easy. Which is why you may want to considering switching to Ti*k*Z, where styles can do all of this with ease.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newif\ifBlackAndWhite  
\BlackAndWhitefalse    

\newcommand\myCommand{\ifBlackAndWhite  
fillstyle=none%
\else
fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red%
\fi}
\def\ePScircle[#1](#2)#3{\expanded{\noexpand\pscircle[#1](#2){#3}}} 
\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=none, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\BlackAndWhitetrue  
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \expanded{\noexpand\pscircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}}
\end{pspicture}

\BlackAndWhitefalse  
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \expanded{\noexpand\pscircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}}
\end{pspicture}


\BlackAndWhitetrue  
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \ePScircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\BlackAndWhitefalse  
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \ePScircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My problem was not really related with pstrick (I just transposed it in this context to avoid a too technical situation), but your solution using \expanded{\noexpand is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

The optional parameters passed to any PStricks object is not expanded. You can redefine the macro that captures the optional parameters - `\pst@@object` - to use an `\edef` instead of a regular `\def`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pst@@object#1[#2]{%
  \edef\pst@par{#2}% Changed from \def to \edef
  \@ifnextchar+{\@nameuse{#1@i}}{\@nameuse{#1@i}}%
}
\makeatother
```

A little more elegant is probably to use an [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\pst@@object}% <cmd>
  {\def}% <search>
  {\edef}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

An `\edef` will expand the parameters once, which is probably sufficient in most cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\pst@@object}% <cmd>
  {\def}% <search>
  {\edef}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\newcommand{\myCommand}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red}

\newif\ifBlackAndWhite  \BlackAndWhitefalse

\ifBlackAndWhite
  \renewcommand{\myCommand}{fillstyle=none}
\fi
  
\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
  \pscircle[fillstyle=none, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
  \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
  \pscircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output with `\BlackAndWhitetrue`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\makeatletter % switch the commented lines for changing the meaning of the key
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{myfill}[]{\setkeys+[psset]{pstricks}{fillstyle=none}}
%\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{myfill}[]{\setkeys+[psset]{pstricks}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
\pscircle[fillstyle=none, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
\pscircle[myfill, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After switching the comments:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant of the [solution of user232027](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577078) which does with `\protected@edef\@tempa{...}` instead of `\expanded{...}`.

I present it only because older TeX-engines don't have `\expanded`.

Nonetheless I definitely prefer the [solution of user232027](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577078) because a disadvantage of my variant is that you need to double hashes within the optional argument.

(I don't know if the optional argument of `\pscircle` can contasin hashes.)

Unlike the [solution of user232027](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577078) where all arguments are expanded my variant does only expand the optional argument if present.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newif\ifBlackAndWhite  
\BlackAndWhitefalse    

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myCommand{%
  \ifBlackAndWhite\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {fillstyle=none}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red}%
}
\newcommand\ePScircle{\@ifnextchar[{\ePScircleOpt}{\pscircle}}%
\newcommand\ePScircleOpt[1][]{%
  {\protected@edef\@tempa{#1}\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\pscircle\expandafter[\expandafter{\@tempa}]%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=none, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\BlackAndWhitetrue  
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \expanded{\noexpand\pscircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}}
\end{pspicture}

\BlackAndWhitefalse  
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \expanded{\noexpand\pscircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}}
\end{pspicture}


\BlackAndWhitetrue  
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \ePScircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\BlackAndWhitefalse  
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \ePScircle[\myCommand, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

[Similar to egreg's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577152) you can define a key which evaluates the `\ifBlackAndWhite`-switch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifBlackAndWhite
\BlackAndWhitefalse

\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{myfill}[]{%
  \ifBlackAndWhite\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\setkeys+[psset]{pstricks}{fillstyle=none}}%
  {\setkeys+[psset]{pstricks}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\BlackAndWhitefalse

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[myfill, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\BlackAndWhitetrue

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pscircle[myfill, linewidth=1mm](1,1){0.5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]